# loop to fit model over all dataframe in floder python

Tags: python, loops, pandas

I`m try to go through all files in folder and do some model like ARIMA for every file 
my code

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from pandas import datetime
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
listing = os.listdir(path)
for infile in listing:
    pd.read_csv(infile,header =0,nrows =2904 ,parse_dates=[0],
                index_col=0,squeeze=True, date_parser=parser)
#    print "current file is: " + infile

   X = df.values
   size = int(len(X) * 0.99)
   train, test = X[0:size], X[size:len(X)]
   history = [x for x in train]
   predictions = list()
   for t in range(len(test)):
      model = ARIMA(history, order=(3,1,0))
      model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
      output = model_fit.forecast()
      yhat = output[0]
      predictions.append(yhat)
      obs = test[t]
      history.append(obs)
      print('predicted=%f, expected=%f' % (yhat, obs))
  rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(test, predictions))
  print('Test RMSE: %.3f' % rmse)
```

the result supposed to be like this

```
file1 RMSE IS : 0.12
file2 RMSE IS : 0.32
file3 RMSE IS : 0.22
.
.
```

but the output just showing the first file in the folder

Answer (score 0):

it does not appear that you are reading the csv into a dataframe.

I think

```
pd.read_csv(infile,header =0,nrows =2904 ,parse_dates=[0],
                index_col=0,squeeze=True, date_parser=parser)
```

should be

```
df = pd.read_csv(infile,header =0,nrows =2904 ,parse_dates=[0],
                index_col=0,squeeze=True, date_parser=parser)
```